# React formik select condition based another select

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am using react formik. I have issues on condition rendering I am working one form that has one check field that field is checked and the selected box will be opened the select box contain two field Free and Paid if they select paid another select field want to opened. I have an issues with second selected because they are not condition rendered

codesandbox link https://yvbm3.csb.app/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your problem is with this check: `values.toggle2.paid ?`. You are trying to see if the `paid` param of the object `toggle2` is truthy, but it will always be falsy, because the value of `toggle2` is a string.

Change your code to: `{values.toggle2 === 'paid' ? (` and it should work.

Here is the complete block:

```js
{values.toggle2 === 'paid' ? (
  <label>
    <Field name="toggle3" displayEmpty variant="outlined" as="select">
      <option value="free">Free</option>
      <option value="paid">Paid</option>
    </Field>
  </label>
) : null}
```